Call a Function on Change MudTabs in Blazor
I am developing an application in .NET 8 Blazor WebAssembly and using the MudBlazor library for the UI. I have a MudTabs component, and I want to call a function whenever I change tabs. How can I achieve this?
<MudTabs Elevation="2" Rounded="true" ApplyEffectsToContainer="true" PanelClass="pa-6">
    <MudTabPanel Text="Tab One">
        <MudText>Content One</MudText>
    </MudTabPanel>
    <MudTabPanel Text="Tab Two">
        <MudText>Content Two</MudText>
    </MudTabPanel>
    <MudTabPanel Text="Tab Three">
        <MudText>Content Three</MudText>
    </MudTabPanel>
</MudTabs>


If you want the function call to be dependant on which tab is clicked, then you can use OnClick on the MudTabPanel
<MudTabs Elevation="2" Rounded="true" ApplyEffectsToContainer="true" PanelClass="pa-6">
    <MudTabPanel Text="Tab One" OnClick="eventArgs=>HandleClick(eventArgs,1)">
        <MudText>Content One</MudText>
    </MudTabPanel>
    <MudTabPanel Text="Tab Two" OnClick="eventArgs=>HandleClick(eventArgs,2)">
        <MudText>Content Two</MudText>
    </MudTabPanel>
    <MudTabPanel Text="Tab Three" OnClick="eventArgs=>HandleClick(eventArgs,3)">
        <MudText>Content Three</MudText>
    </MudTabPanel>
</MudTabs>

@_value

@code{
    int _value;
    void HandleClick(MouseEventArgs eventArgs,int passedValue){
        _value = passedValue;
        Console.WriteLine(passedValue);
    }
}

Demo  MudBlazor Snippet

You can bind to the ActivePanelIndex and use the after event to call a method.
See the demo below:
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<MudText Typo="Typo.h3" GutterBottom="true">Hello, world!</MudText>
<MudText Class="mb-8">Welcome to your new app, powered by MudBlazor and the .NET 8 Template!</MudText>

<MudTabs Elevation="2"
         Rounded="true"
         ApplyEffectsToContainer="true"
         PanelClass="pa-6"
         @bind-ActivePanelIndex="_tabIndex"
         @bind-ActivePanelIndex:after="this.OnTabIndexChanged">

    <MudTabPanel Text="Tab One">
        <MudText>Content One</MudText>
    </MudTabPanel>

    <MudTabPanel Text="Tab Two">
        <MudText>Content Two</MudText>
    </MudTabPanel>

    <MudTabPanel Text="Tab Three">
        <MudText>Content Three</MudText>
    </MudTabPanel>

</MudTabs>

<MudAlert Severity="Severity.Normal">
    @_message
</MudAlert>

@code {
    private int _tabIndex;
    private string? _message;

    private Task OnTabIndexChanged()
    {
        _message = $"Changed at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()} to {_tabIndex}";
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

